# "https://fls.doubleclick.net" tracking downloads "http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"

Tags: google-floodlight

I had this Google floodlight code on a secure page in one of the websites I maintain. This content is inside and iframe which in turn is inside :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.write ('<IFRAME  src="https://fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=XXXXX;type=12312;cat=084;qty=1;cost=$iTotal;?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="1" style="display:none" 
 </IFRAME>')
 </script>
```

recently IE issued a message stating the page has insecure content. Inspecting the page with fiddler I can see that now the Google server that receives the floodlights also sends back a javascript library:

```
         "http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"
```

which is causing the insecure content message.

Has this happened to you too? Any idea how to fix it?

I found a tag I didn't knew on doubleclick:

```
<img src="https://gan.doubleclick.net/gan_conversion?advid=K123456&oid=12345&amt=123.45" width=1 height=1>
```

but It's not very clear if it does the same thing.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In the corrosponding Google Floodlight activity, you'll want to check the box that says "Secure Servers Only (https)".